# How can get user id from database to arrowchat intergration

Tags: database

In my php i have this code, to see if the user is logged in

```
$auth=new auth();
$username = $auth->loggedIn();
global $crt_usr;
if(!$username) { header("Location: ".$config_live_site."/login.php?loc=account_info.php"); exit(0); }
$smarty->assign("username",$username);

$usr = new users();
$user = $usr->getUser($crt_usr);
$smarty->assign("user",$user);
```

And i have and this intergraton for the arrowchat

```
function get_user_id() 
{
    $userid = NULL;

    if (isset($_COOKIE['userid']))
    {
        $userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

My user id field name in my database is "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a session that have your user id and put it to the `get_user_id()` function

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
```